# Firebase: Failed to initialize crash reporting

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-crash-reporting

My build.gradle file

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.4.0'
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.4.0"
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:9.4.0'

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

This is how i am initializing FireBase Crash:

```
FirebaseCrash.report(new Exception("My first Android non-fatal error"));
```

but I am getting this from Logcat:

```
 Failed to initialize crash reporting
  com.google.firebase.crash.internal.zzg$zza: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzsb$zza: 
No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
```

Comment: Could you update this with the version of Play Services that's installed on the device you're testing with?

Comment: @DougStevenson I was testing in emulator and Play services is updated. 
Downgrading  to firebase 9.0.2  solves the issue.

Comment: You should always be able to use the latest client libraries.  Can you verify the version of Play Services that is running on the emulator?  That's the important part.

Answer (score 5):

Crash reporting won't initialize if you don't have updated Google Play Services on your device or you haven't it installed at all.

Comment: Google play service is installed and  updated on my device but still getting this error

Comment: this error is thrown only when you don't have google play services installed or updated, so try it on emulator with Google APIs and see if it works

Comment: What is strange is that according to the documentation it should work: "Crashlytics does work on devices that do not have Google Play services."
https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?authuser=0&platform=android

Answer (score 1):

I agree with `@user6749691` that the failure is most likely caused by Google Play Services being old or not present.  The issue is [discussed here](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/issues/14).

You can confirm that your installed Play Services is sufficient to support Firebase by adding this method and calling it when your app initializes:

```
private void showGooglePlayServicesStatus() {
    GoogleApiAvailability apiAvail = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
    int errorCode = apiAvail.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    String msg = "Play Services: " + apiAvail.getErrorString(errorCode);
    Log.d(TAG, msg);
    Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check for typos, that can be a reason too.

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:11.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.0.1'
```

Silly mistake, hard to spot, but for e.g. I had x.x.1, instead of x.x.2, and all Firebase / Google Play Service libs should use the same version.